# Formula to generate a value according to a range

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, lookup, worksheet-function

I want to populate a cell according to the range of another cell. Like if the independent cell has the value between `12` to `16` then the dependent cell will be populated as `-2` and if the independent cell has a value between `16` to `20` then `-1` and if `20`-`24` then `N` and so on:

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDzMl.png)
[image: Sample]

Is there any formula or how otherwise can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just before the answer was posted, I was going to ask if you had tried anything yourself? Also, what happens if the independent cell contains (say) 25?

Comment: Thanks for the question and sorry for delay in answer. It will be "2". No i have no clue on how to do it. Though I have done such things in SPSS but not in EXCEL.

Comment: I should rather tell you the whole story. I will use it to convert BMI to BMI classification so at most it will range from -4 to +4. There should not be any value above 40 ideally but we will consider them as Extreme outliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `16` is "between" 16-20 rather than "between" 12-16 and that for `N` it is the text of the OP that counts rather than the image:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{12,16,20,24},{-2,-1,"N"})
```

Negative values, zero, numbers less than 12 and positive or greater than 24, blanks and text would return `#N/A`.

[LOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb).

Comment: Again thank you Pnuts, It is working flawlessly. I guess i have to add 30 and 1 to get a "1" for value ranging from 24 to 30, right? Thanks again its a great help! As i am getting into excel i hope to see you geeks around :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this (place this formula in `B1`):

```
=IF(AND(A1>=12;A1<=15);"-2";IF(AND(A1>=16;A1<20);"-1";IF(AND(A1>=20;A1<25);"N";"N/A")))
```

Comment: Hello Manu, Thanks a lot for your time N help. I can make out the ligic in this code but sadly its not working for me may be some mistake on my part. Don't know why its not converting to numbers instead its just showing as it is. I dont know how add a image in comment.

Comment: Maybe convert he semi column by ";" by come "," (it depends of the excel version)

Comment: Right on target Buddy! After changing to coma it worked! So which version you are using?